# Pass Two values when a Submit button is clicked -PHP

Tags: php

This table is displaying details about my workload table per row. And when I click my "pre-View_attend" submit button I want to get the "WorkloadID" and "subjectID" of that workload row where the submit button was clicked.

Currently I have a hidden field containing the subject ID which is "subjectID_hidden", and when I try to get the "WorkloadID" and "subjectID" by using isset.

It seems that I can't accurately get the exact subject ID of the row where I've clicked the "pre-View_attend"  submit button.

```html
<tbody style="font-size:20px; text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["subjectName"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["className"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["RoomNumber"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Sched_Days.'<br>'.$FST.' To '.$FET;?></td>
<td><button style="font-size:15px;" type="button" id="<?php echo $row["WorkloadID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary view_StudentList">View Student List</button></td>
<td><button style="font-size:15px;" type="submit" name="gettingAttendance" value="<?php echo $row["WorkloadID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Take Attendance</button></td>
<td><button style="font-size:15px;" type="submit" name="pre-View_attend" value="<?php echo $row["WorkloadID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Attendance</button></td>
<input type="hidden" name="subjectID_hidden" value="<?php echo $row["subjectID"]; ?>">
</tr> 
<?php }  mysqli_close($connect);?> 
  </tbody>
 /*
 I'm getting the workload ID accurately, but the subject ID is incorrect.
I believe I'm getting the last subject ID that my query produced
 */ 
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['pre-View_attend']))
 { $FWID=$_POST['pre-View_attend'];
   $FSJID=$_POST['subjectID_hidden'];   
echo"Workload ID: $FWID SubjectID: $FSJID";
 }  
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the last value because you have a bunch of hidden fields with the same name.

You could name them `subjectID_hidden[<?=$row['WorkloadID'];?>]` to get an array to then get the `subjectID` by `WorkloadID`:

```
$subjectID = $_POST["subjectID_hidden"][$_POST["pre-View_attend"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the table for something unique to the row you want to retrieve information from. This unqiue data should already be existing on the page, encoded into the button/form.
Example;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pre-View_attend'])) {
global $db;
$select = "select * from mytable where unique='$unique'";
$connect = mysqli_query($db, $select);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($connect)) {
$myfirstVariable = $row['myfirstVariable'];
$mysecondVariable = $row['mysecondVariable'];
$show = "$myfirstVariable $mysecondVariable";
}
}
?>
```

Then you can call $show when you want in the HTML.
p.s. there are quite a few errors in your html like;

```
<input type="hidden" name="subjectID_hidden" value="<?php echo $row["subjectID"]; ?>">
```

should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="subjectID_hidden" value="<?php echo $row["subjectID"]; ?>" />
```

self closing at the end with forwards slash.